# Mensaje de confirmacion phpmailer

Tags: php, javascript, html, phpmailer

estoy haciendo una web(recien estoy aprendiendo) e hice un formulario de contacto con phpmailer, me envia todo correctamente pero lo que quiero es cambiar el mensaje de confirmacion cuando se envia el email osea ahora me redirige al contact.php y me muestra jn texto comun lo que quisiera es que me muestre un alert o que aparezca el mensaje de que se envio debajo de mi formulario si es posible sin que recarge, investigue y probe pero nada me funciona. Desde ya gracias 
mi index.html esta asi

```
<form name="sentMessage" method="post" action="php/contacto.php" id="contact-form" role="form" class="animated bounceInLeft">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre *" name="name" required="" data-validation-required-message="Por favor ingrese su nombre.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail *" name="email" required="" data-validation-required-message="Por favor un e-mail valido.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Numero *" name="phone" required="" data-validation-required-message="Por favor ingrese su numero .">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Mensaje *" name="message" required="" data-validation-required-message="Porfavor ponga un mensaje."></textarea>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <div id="success"></div>
            <button type="submit" id="submit" form-id="contactForm" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg get enviar-boton">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Y mi php usando phpmailer termina en:

```
if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Gracias por contactarnos");</script>';
}
```

solo me sale el alert en una nueva pagina y despues pagina en blanco.

Comment: Te sugiero que **[edites la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/97802/edit)** poniendo el código que has probado y no funciona. Y si tienes el mensaje de error, inclúyelo también en la pregunta, de esa forma podrás obtener con más rapidez una posible solución a tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

según tienes esto montado, después de mandar el correo deberías redireccionar con un header() a la misma página de contacto y pasarle un parámetro para saber que todo ha ido correcto, y cambiar tu contact.php para que después del formulario, lea si esa variable existe, y si existe pintarte el mensaje que quieres, por ejemplo:

```
if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
   header("location: contact.php?enviado=1");
}
```

El php de envió del correo quedaría así, por otro lado.... en tu contact.php deberías añadir esto:

```
<!-- El resto de tu código vendria aqui arriba, por no copiar todo -->
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <div id="success"></div>
        <button type="submit" id="submit" form-id="contactForm" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg get enviar-boton">Enviar</button>
    </div>
<?php 
     if(isset($_GET['enviado']){
         if($_GET['enviado'] == 1){
             echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Gracias por contactarnos");</script>';
         }
     }
?>
```

De esta manera, cuando alguien entre a tu página no aparecerá mensaje, pero al rellenar el formulario y redirigirte a la página con ese parámetro "enviado=1" ya lo detecta y te muestra el mensaje.

Pero ya te digo, que este tipo de cosas no se hacen así, deberías usar javascript, jQuery para que te sea mas sencillo y hacer todas estas peticiones por AJAX para enviar a un php datos y que te devuelva una respuesta sin recargar la página.

Espero que se haya entendido, un saludo.

Comment: Eso estube buscando, hacerlo con ajax pero  no logro entender bien como hacerlo y cuandl lo intento no me sale. Si tendrias algun enlace para guiarme mejor te agradeceria ya que quiero que me envie la espuesta sin recargar.

Comment: Un ejemplo concreto de lo uque tu tienes no encuentro, pero lo mas parecido es esto, recoge datos de un formulario y los envia por ajax a un php. Échale un vistazo y si te surgen dudas por aqui ando, no es muy dificil implementarlo con jQuery. http://www.miguelmanchego.com/2009/ajax-enviar-formularios-sin-recargar-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Saben estuve intentando de todo con ajax pero aun asi me sigue enviando a mi a mi php de contacto luego de enviar el formulario